# on calling new created controller function it navigates to 404 error page

Tags: php, yii2

in yii2 advanced template site Controller is working fine. When calling a function in new controller it is navigating to 404 error page.

I created model using model generator and create a crude for the model.

This is my controller

```
 namespace backend\Controllers;

    use Yii;
    use common\models\PackageTable;
    use common\models\PackageTableSearch;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

    /**
     * PackageTableController implements the CRUD actions for PackageTable model.
     */
    class PackageTableController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['POST'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Lists all PackageTable models.
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $searchModel = new PackageTableSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Displays a single PackageTable model.
         * @param integer $id
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionView($id)
        {
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new PackageTable model.
         * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new PackageTable();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->package_id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Updates an existing PackageTable model.
         * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
         * @param integer $id
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->package_id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Deletes an existing PackageTable model.
         * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
         * @param integer $id
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionDelete($id)
        {
            $this->findModel($id)->delete();

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        /**
         * Finds the PackageTable model based on its primary key value.
         * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
         * @param integer $id
         * @return PackageTable the loaded model
         * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
         */
        protected function findModel($id)
        {
            if (($model = PackageTable::findOne($id)) !== null) {
                return $model;
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my model

```
    <?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "package_table".
 *
 * @property integer $package_id
 * @property string $package_name
 * @property string $description
 * @property integer $amount
 * @property integer $status
 * @property string $created_on
 * @property string $updated_on
 */
class PackageTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'package_table';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['package_name', 'description', 'amount', 'status'], 'required'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['amount', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['created_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
            [['package_name'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'package_id' => 'Package ID',
            'package_name' => 'Package Name',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'amount' => 'Amount',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_on' => 'Created On',
            'updated_on' => 'Updated On',
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my model search

```
 <?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\PackageTable;

/**
 * PackageTableSearch represents the model behind the search form about `common\models\PackageTable`.
 */
class PackageTableSearch extends PackageTable
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['package_id', 'amount', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['package_name', 'description', 'created_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = PackageTable::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'package_id' => $this->package_id,
            'amount' => $this->amount,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'created_on' => $this->created_on,
            'updated_on' => $this->updated_on,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'package_name', $this->package_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: Please check my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although php namespaces are case-insensitive, autoloader in your case is likely case-sensitive.

At the top of your controller namespace mentioned as

```
 namespace backend/Controllers;
```

but in advanced template all directories are in lower case. So try to change this line to

```
 namespace backend/controllers;
```